# Best way to maximize this multivariable function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to maximize the function $f:\Bbb R^{12}\to\Bbb R$ given by 
$$\begin{align*}
&f(x_1^{(1)},x_1^{(2)},x_2^{(1)},x_2^{(2)},x_3^{(1)},x_3^{(2)},y_1^{(1)},x_1^{(2)},y_2^{(1)},y_2^{(2)},y_3^{(1)},y_3^{(2)})=\\&\frac{1}{2}(-x_1^{(1)} y_1^{(1)} - x_1^{(2)} y_1^{(2)}) + \frac{1}{2} (-x_3^{(1)} y_1^{(1)} - x_3^{(2)} y1^{(2)})+ \\&\frac{1}{2} (-x_1^{(1)} y_3^{(1)} - x_1^{(2)} y_3^{(2)}) + \frac{1}{2} (x_3^{(1)} y_3^{(1)} + x_3^{(2)} y_3^{(2)})
\end{align*}$$
with the constraint
$$(x_i^{(1)},x_i^{(2)}),(y_i^{(1)},y_i^{(2)})\in\Bbb S^1, i=1,2,3.$$

(notation: $\Bbb S^1=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2; x^2+y^2=1\}$).

What is the best way to do that?

**My attempt:** I thought Lagrange Multipliers would be the best way to do it, but before the implementation, I tried to `Maximize`. Don't works for this, the program runs forever. For the Lagrange Multiplies approach, my code was

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[x11_, x12_, x21_, x22_, x31_, x32_, y11_, y12_, y21_, y22_, y31_, 
  y32_] := 1/2*(-x11 y11 - x12 y12) + 1/2*(-x31 y11 - x32 y12) + 
  1/2*(-x11 y31 - x12 y32) + 1/2*(x31 y31 + x32 y32)
const1 = -1 + x11^2 + x12^2;
const2 = -1 + x21^2 + x22^2;
const3 = -1 + x31^2 + x32^2;
const4 = -1 + y11^2 + y12^2;
const5 = -1 + y21^2 + y22^2;
const6 = -1 + y31^2 + y32^2;
sols = Solve[{const1 == 0, const2 == 0, const3 == 0, const4 == 0, 
    const5 == 0, const6 == 0, 
    Grad[f[x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, 
       y32], {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, 
       y32}] == 
     lambda1 Grad[
        const1, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}] + 
      lambda2 Grad[
        const2, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}] + 
      lambda3 Grad[
        const3, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}] + 
      lambda4 Grad[
        const4, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}] + 
      lambda5 Grad[
        const5, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}] + 
      lambda6 Grad[
        const6, {x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, 
         y31, y32}]}];
values = f[x11, x12, x21, x22, x31, x32, y11, y12, y21, y22, y31, y32] /. sols
Max[values]
```

There is a problem again. It seems that there are a lot of critical points. `Max[values]` returned some values in function of $y_3^{(1)}$. What can I do now? Maximize each expression in function of $y_3^{(1)}$ again? I only want the maximum *value* attained by $f$ in $\Bbb S^1\times\cdots\times\Bbb S^1$, don't care about the points where the maximum is attained. I don't know if it is $\sqrt{2}$ or not.

The last thing I tried was `NMaximize`. It returns almost immediately the value $\sqrt{2}$. Is this maximum global of local? I will work with lots of functions like the one above. Will `NMaximize` always gives-me global maxima for this kind of functions?

Comment: Is there some geometric background for this?

Comment: No much. These functions are obtained through the dot product for vectors, like $f=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}\langle x_i,y_j \rangle$, with $x_i, y_i\in\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: You can try parametrizing your constraint, i.e. writing $$x_i^{(1)}=\cos(\theta_i),\quad x_i^{(2)}=\sin(\theta_i)$$ this reduces the  dimensionality from 12 to 6, which is a lot. You pay by not having a quadratic function to minimize. My intuition is that that either with or without this trick the minimization should be simple since it's a convex function over a compact domain and out-of-the-box methods should do just fine

Comment: @yohbs So will `NMaximize` always find a global maximum? It would be awesome

Comment: No, that's not guaranteed, so you need to play with the method and method settings.

Comment: I'm just saying that in general `NMaximize[]` won't find the global optimum. It will certainly try its best, tho.

Answer (score 1):

The function has a 4-dimensional manifold of maximizers. To see this, do the change of variables as I suggested in the comments:

```
f2 = FullSimplify[1/2*(-x11 y11 - x12 y12) + 1/2*(-x31 y11 - x32 y12) + 
 1/2*(-x11 y31 - x12 y32) + 1/2*(x31 y31 + x32 y32)/. {x11 -> Cos[q1], x12 -> Sin[q1], x21 -> Cos[q2], 
   x22 -> Sin[q2], x31 -> Cos[q3], x32 -> Sin[q3],
   y11 -> Cos[q4], y12 -> Sin[q4], y21 -> Cos[q5], y22 -> Sin[q5], 
   y31 -> Cos[q6], y32 -> Sin[q6]}]
```

and you'll find the much simpler function:

```
1/2 (-Cos[q1 - q4] - Cos[q3 - q4] - Cos[q1 - q6] + Cos[q3 - q6])
```

Since the maximal value of each cosine is clearly 1, the maximal value of the function is 2, and is obtained whenever `q1-q4==Pi`, `q3-q4==Pi` and so on.

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere. The maximum of this function cannot be 2.

Comment: Maybe. Did you notice the function does not depend on `x21` and on `y21`?

Comment: is this a problem? The function of the OP uses only 8 variables from the 12 available. Anyway, the code should handle any other similar function.

Comment: `NMaximize[{1/
    2 (-Cos[q1 - q4] - Cos[q3 - q4] - Cos[q1 - q6] + Cos[q3 - q6]), 
  Thread[0 <= {q1, q3, q4, q6} <= 2 Pi]}, {q1, q3, q4, q6}]`also gives `Sqrt[2]`.